# Is there an easy way to fix indentation style mistakes in github repo?

Tags: git, github, indentation, collaboration

I am working with some of my colleagues in various github repo, in various languages, but it is often hard to keep a clear track of changes because a lot of the diff picked up by github is due to different indent styles.

Besides changing our settings on each of our editors to make sure they are the same, is there a tool to fix the indentation automatically on github ?

The main problem is with R files.

Thanks !

Comment: If you have specific coding standards (and you really should), the normal thing to do is reject the pull request until the author fixes it. Or you can probably install a git hook on commit/merge to prevent it without thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the build in feature to ignore white spaces.

[image]